# Exclude hidden folders to generate archetype

Tags: maven, maven-archetype

I'm using the command:

```
mvn archetype:create-from-project -Darchetype.properties=./archetype.properties
```

I want exclude hidden dirs, for example .sonar, I try the follow options:

```
excludePatterns=**/*sonar/*
```

and

```
excludePatterns=**/.sonar/*
```

but not working form me, with non hidden dirs work well. 
How can I exclude hidden directories?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a bug in version 2.4 of the Archetype Plugin in which certain files that match the exclude patterns are still included. I created [ARCHETYPE-513](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-513) to track this and this bug has been fixed for version 3.0.0 of the plugin. Thus, make sure you use this version by specifying in your POM:

```
<build>
  <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-archetype-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

To recap, the `excludePatterns` property should be present in the property file, configured with [`propertyFile`](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/create-from-project-mojo.html#propertyFile) or the `-Darchetype.properties` user property, that is used by the plugin. So the following `archetype.properties` property file:

```
excludePatterns=**/.sonar/**
```

used with `mvn clean archetype:create-from-project -Darchetype.properties=archetype.properties` will correctly exclude all folders named `.sonar` that are present in your project when the archetype is created.

Comment: Does it now work in version 2.4? Another question, is that if I add the property "excludePatterns" in the file archetype.properties. It then exits as a custom property when generating an application. And "archetype.excludePatterns" does not work. Thanks.

Comment: @oscar Yes, it mostly works in 2.4. I discovered that bug while researching this question and fixed it. And yes, what you found out about this, generating a new custom property, is also a bug fixed in 2.5, see [ARCHETYPE-504](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARCHETYPE-504).

Comment: @oscar FYI, version 3.0.0 containing this bug fix was released.